# Overlapping hallow/unhallow effects

Tags: spells, dnd-3e

The *hallow* and *unhallow* spells cancel each other by overlapping.

Does this mean the attached spell (e.g. silence) is canceled as well?

Comment: My question was a bit off target because of a bad translation in the Italian manual, reading *Counters and dispel* instead of *counters but not dispel*. JonathanHobbs's answer made me aware of the bad assumption in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from the 3e SRD articles on [Unhallow](http://www.zombler.org/files/srd30a/spellsuvwxyz.htm) and [Hallow](http://www.zombler.org/files/srd30a/spellsh.htm), they both mention this:

> Unhallow counters but does not dispel hallow.

> Hallow counters but does not dispel unhallow.

It explicitly states the land is still both hallowed and unhallowed, and doesn't suggest that anything happens to their spell effects (if it does, that's very, very unclear). For that matter, a body in such an area can *still* not be turned into an undead creature, since the hallowed area effects are still in play.